# JSON: add values in square brackets without commas

Tags: php, json

I just created an array using PHP. there is a value of key like

```
"coordinates": "[-104.98999178409576, 39.74683938093904]"
```

I created it using

```
$array["coordinates"] = "[". $lat " , " $lng "]";
```

I don't want the `"` to  be there. here is the expected result in JSON

```
"coordinates": [-104.98999178409576, 39.74683938093904]
```

Comment: So create an array: `array($lat, lng)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're manually trying to write JSON in an array which you then JSON encode. Don't do that. Create your PHP array structure and then encode the whole thing into JSON in one go:

```
$array["coordinates"] = array($lat, $lng);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: That may need a `+$lat, +$lng` to coerce the values into numbers before encoding it.

Comment: Whatever (float)s your boat :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
json_encode(array('coordinates' => array(-104.98999178409576, 39.74683938093904)));
```